# Is Angular 4 material responsive like bootstrap?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material2

I am starting on a new project with Angular 4 and need to create responsive and pleasant user interface.

- bootstrap gives you responsiveness, but no material feel
- angular material provides that nice UI experience https://material.angular.io

I know bootstrap and used it in previous AngularJS apps, but angular material is new to me. It seems easy to follow docs but i cannot find the responsiveness support.

I don't want to mix them but have not been able to find that column responsiveness for mobile support that bootstrap provides.

**Am I missing something? Does angular material support similar responsiveness or should I used both in my app?**

Comment: Check @angular/flex-layout. The material components are responsive up to some extent (font size, text decorators, etc), but to create responsive layouts, angular offers the mentioned package.

Comment: will it work with @angular/material without conflicts?

Comment: yes, no problems

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To add responsiveness in modern angular app you can use [Flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) it is completely separate from [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) so you can use that even without using material2 in your app.

Bare in mind that as [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is based on [Flexbox CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) so it is [not supported in old browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Here are some [examples](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

Also check out the new [ngAir episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TewrxMo_QAs&feature=youtu.be&a) episode talking about [Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

UPDATE:

Starting from [6.0.0-beta.16](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-beta16-2018-06-07) [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) now has an [API to support CSS Grid](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YjKHAV7-wh5UZd4snoyw6bVWe1X5JF-zDaUFa8-JDtE/edit). You can find more details by checking [pr#712](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/pull/712)

Comment: I laughed when I tried it and learned that it just shrinks the contents instead of letting each contents collapse naturally as the view size changes. :D

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Have you gone through [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) for flexbox ?

Comment: But it seems that all the releases are in beta

Comment: @AbhinandanKhilari https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/713

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I have created a starter template that shows an example of a responsive layout with Material 5 and Angular 5 as well as some simple routing.
https://github.com/kenji-1996/material-sidenav-responsive-starter

Uses Material and Flex, no outside libs