# MediaObserver vs BreakpointObserver - what are the differences?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, media-queries, angular-cdk

After doing some searching, I came to realize that I'm supposed to use the [Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) library to make Material-themed UI responsive (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290746/is-angular-4-material-responsive-like-bootstrap)). And according to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation), this library provides the `MediaObserver` class to programmatically detect media query activation.

I used the material schematics command -

```
ng g @angular/material:navigation shell/layout
```

to add a `Sidenav` component, and noticed the following generated code -

```js
export class LayoutComponent {
    isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
        map(result => result.matches),
        shareReplay()
    );

    constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { } 
}
```

It is using the `BreakpointObserver` class and predefined `Breakpoints` from `@angular/cdk/layout` package to detect viewport changes. And the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) says -

> The layout package provides utilities to build responsive UIs that
> react to screen-size changes.

So, apparently, there are two different libraries available for making Material-themed UI responsive and they use different approaches. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'd like to know -

- From usage perspective what are the differences between these two libraries/packages, that is, when to use which?
- Does `MediaObserver` uses `BreakpointObserver` under-the-hood?
- If I use Flex-Layout, should I avoid `@angular/cdk/layout` utilities altogether? Are there some best practices to follow in this regard?

**Edit: 2020.05.11**
According to the source code of `MediaObserver`, it doesn't use the `BreakpointObserver` under-the-hood. It uses the native `Window.matchMedia()` API instead.

Answer (score 1):

From : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/685

> @angular/cdk BreakpointObserver will not replace @angular/flex-layout MediaObserver.
> MediaObserver is an enhanced version that notifies subscribers of activations for standard AND overlapping (lt-xxx, gt-xxx) breakpoints.